# Concatenate string columns and index

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
A    B
----------
c    d
e    f
```

I'd like to introduce a third column, made up of a concatenation of `A`, `B` and the index, so that the `DataFrame` becomes:

```
A    B    C
---------------
c    d    cd0
e    f    ef1
```

I'd like to do that like so:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'] + # and here I don't know how to reference the row index.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
For better scalability, use `assign` + `agg`:

```
df['C'] = df.assign(index=df.index.astype(str)).agg(''.join, 1)
df

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

Or, using `np.add.reduce` in a similar fashion:

```
df['C'] = np.add.reduce(df.assign(index=df.index.astype(str)), axis=1)
df

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

---

**Option 2**
A less scalable option using vectorised string concatenation:

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B'] + df.index.astype(str)
df

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**With `pd.DataFrame.itertuples`**
Python 3.6

```
df.assign(C=[f'{a}{b}{i}' for i, a, b in df.itertuples()])

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

---

**With `pd.Series.str.cat`**

```
df.assign(C=df.A.str.cat(df.B).str.cat(df.index.astype(str)))

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

---

**Mish/Mash**

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain

df.assign(C=reduce(add, chain((df[c] for c in df), [df.index.astype(str)])))

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

---

**Summation**

```
df.assign(C=df.sum(1) + df.index.astype(str))

   A  B    C
0  c  d  cd0
1  e  f  ef1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C'] = df['A'].astype(str) + df['B'].astype(str) + np.array(map(str, df.index.values))
```

Basically you access the df index with df.index, and to turn that into a numpy array you add the .values, and to convert that into a string (to easily add to the previous columns, which are strings), you can use a map function.

Edit: added .astype(str) to columns A and B, to convert them to strings. If they are already strings, this won't be necessary.

Comment: doesn't work for me, unfortunately: I get a `TypeError: must be str, not map`

Comment: Always prefer `astype` when performing type conversions in numpy/pandas. Also, your code works only in python2 only, unless you collect the output of `map` to a list.

Comment: @Zubo Your columns A and B must not already be strings types then. I edited my post with .astype(str) commands to convert them to strings. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for the tip COLDSPEED.